# (Go) How can I use GDB debug on IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, go, gdb

I'm developping golang porjects using IntelliJ IDEA 15.
In advance I installed GDB to debug on mac.
Then I want to debug golang projects using GDB on IntelliJ IDEA.
However, I could't find how I can do that.

If someone know, please give me a advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA version is 15 and Community Edition.

Comment: Are you using the [Go IntelliJ plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that. But I can't debug on IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, no, you cannot. However the plugin comes with Delve integrated which makes the debugging experience better for Go apps (if you are on the supported platforms by delve). See the debugger link: https://github.com/derekparker/delve

Once GDB will properly support Go apps, things might change of course.

Comment: Thank you for your great help.
I posted about it on some platform like https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1969

Thanks again!